# Hooks in Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, hook, windows-store-apps

I am trying to extract UI data from a Windows Store App. So far I have tried SetWinEventHook but have had little success. I have also tried to install a setWindowsHookEx hook into a windows store app, but it returns a 0.
MSDN has very little documentation available on this topic. What is the best way of hooking a metro app? Also if there is any other way to extract UI data?

Links:

http://community.nvda-project.org/ticket/1801

http://forum.nektra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6228

Have not been able to figure out how the above links got this done.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this with a window hook? Most store apps don't use standard windows controls (they don't have windows in the normal sense).

I would try UI automation to enumerate the visible controls and interact with them, that might work.

Comment: I have tried with UIAutomation as well using the Managed UIAutomation API. However not been able to extract data from HTML apps or data from apps having controls with dynamic data.

Please share a tested sample for UIAutomation.

P.S. - what do you mean by standard windows controls?